# Laravel dusk tests in gitlab with docker - Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Tags: docker, gitlab, laravel-dusk

When running laravel-dusk on in a docker container on gitlab I get an error saying it cannot connect to port 9515 on localhost.

`Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused`

My docker file looks as following:

```
# Set the base image for subsequent instructions
FROM php:7.1

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Install packages
RUN apt-get update -yqq && apt-get install -y git wget curl libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq bzip2 libfontconfig xvfb chromium libmagickwand-dev

# Add chrome repo and install google-chrome-stable
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Install php environment
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring mcrypt pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache bcmath

# Install imagick
RUN pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

# check installed modules
RUN php -m

# Install NVM
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.1.4
RUN curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash

# install node and npm
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# add node and npm to path so the commands are available
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

# Install Composer Package manager
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && php composer-setup.php \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update

# Xdebug
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug \
&& rm -rf /tmp/* \ && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Clear out the local repository of retrieved package files
RUN apt-get clean


# Install Laravel Envoy
RUN composer global require "laravel/envoy=~1.0"

# confirm installed versions
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN php -v
RUN google-chrome-stable --version
RUN composer --version
RUN php -m

EXPOSE 9515
```

Then my gitlab-ci file looks like the following:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/path-to-repo/repo-name:latest

# Select what we should cache
cache:
    paths:
    - vendor/

services:
- mysql:5.7

variables:
    # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
    MYSQL_DATABASE: database-name
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: database-password
    DB_HOST: mysql
    DB_USERNAME: root

stages:
  - test

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cp .env.runnable .env
    - composer install
    - php artisan config:clear
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate --seed
    - php artisan db:seed --class=TestSeeder
    - vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
    - php artisan env
    - php artisan dusk
```

At first I thought it was because I was not exposing port 9515, but I have exposed this in the Dockerfile. However, now I have no idea what the problem could be. Is there an issues that this port is used for another process? Could it be that the Chromedriver is running on a different port?

Answer (score 3):

In your gitlab-ci file try to replace `php artisan dusk` with:

```
php artisan serve & php artisan dusk
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the 9515 connection refused error and then I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/50#issuecomment-290970530) and added these dependencies to my dockerfile (granted Im using custom ubuntu image). I didn't need to add anything else that the GitHub comment mentions (no script etc).

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# ... my other previous dependencies (PHP, etc.)

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install libxpm4 libxrender1 libgtk2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4 && \
  apt-get -y install chromium-browser && \
  apt-get -y install xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf && \
  apt-get -y install xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable && \
  apt-get -y install imagemagick x11-apps && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

Also, for local development I needed to update my `.env` (or use `.env.dusk.local`) APP_URL: to point to my docker host.

```
APP_URL=host.docker.internal:8000
```

For GitLab, you can try and update your .env `APP_URL` with the docker host by adding an additional setup in a before_script (after copying .env.example to .env). (host.docker.internal is not available in docker for linux). Also, Note your container will need `net-tools` for the netstat command.

```
before_script:
# ...
- docker_host=$(netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}') && sed -i "s|APP_URL=http://0.0.0.0|APP_URL=http://${docker_host}|" .env
```

Where `APP_URL=http://0.0.0.0` is the value of what is already in your existing .env file.